# in Eclipse, how to run all junit tests that reference one class

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

lets say we have class A,
and I have a lot of junit classes, what is the easiest way to run all junit or all junit classes that make a reference to this class A?

for example,

1. look for all references of the class in the project.
2. something in the view to run all junit

Comment: If you're trying to find out whether your changes in class A have broken anything, it's safest just to re-run all your tests.  That's what they're for.

Comment: yes but sometimes you gotta go faster, with a subset.

Comment: But there's no simple way to identify which tests run code that might touch class A. Not saying it's impossible; just not simple.  Don't spend three hours hunting down dependencies, in order to save ten minutes of unit testing time.  Just run all the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, Eclipse is supposed to have a feature exactly for this purpose. Under the "Search" menu, there is an item labeled "Referring Tests...".

[image]

According to the Eclipse documentation, this command:

> Finds all JUnit tests that refer to the currently selected type

Unfortunately, it appears that this feature still [does not work](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508595).

Maybe it's a sign it's just as well to run all the tests, as mentioned in the comments.